# How to hook WooCommerce full description outside of tabs

Tags: php, hook-woocommerce

I tried to hook the product description between the single product summary section and before the pricing area. I used the following hook on my function.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 30 );
```

But fact is, it pools the whole tabs between the short description and price area. I don't need the tab function out there. I just want to add only description area [ like call only the_content() part ]

Is there any option to do that? No styling or functions of tabs, just only pull the content on that place.

Thanks in advance :-)